# Statement cannot be resolved to a type in JSP File

Tags: java, jsp

While running Pregister.jsp file it showing follwing

```
An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /pregister.jsp
Statement cannot be resolved to a type
PreparedStatement cannot be resolved to a type
```

**My code**

```
try {
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");      
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     String query="select email from patient where email=? ";
     PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
     ps.setString(1, pemail);
```

Could any one tell me why I'm getting this error Also suggest me how to solve this error. This file placed under the webapps in tomcat. please suggest this solution

Answer (score 6):

You are missing `java.sql` imports:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
```